# How to display image using django

Tags: python, html, django

I am having trouble on how to display an image on html? i just want to display all image that saves on my database

```
{% for banner in banners %}
<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ banner.banner }}" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">{{banner.title}}</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

model

```
class Banner(models.Model):
    banner = models.ImageField(upload_to='image/', null=True, blank=True)
```

views

```
def homepage(request):
    banners = Banner.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'mysite/homepage.html', {'banners': banners})
```

result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMwL5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 'url' property of the ImageField.

Try this:

```
{{ banner.banner.url }}
```

Comment: Hi Noman, I've tried youre answer but it didnt work on my end

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: "didn't work" is not a good problem description... what happened? if you view source on the generated page, what is generated? if you go to that url, what happens? etc. (you need to provide details)

Comment: I dont have error encountered the problem is it didnt display the image

Comment: @NomanGhani please see the image i posted, thanks

Comment: @Yuno, is the image getting uploaded? Please check in the folder, that is the first step.

Comment: Yes, the image is uploaded via django-admin

Comment: @Yuno, you need to add some configs for this to properly work, read here: https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-file-and-image-uploads-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

models.py

```
class Banner(models.Model):
    banner = models.ImageField(upload_to='image/', null=True, blank=True)

    def get_banner_url(self):
        return self.banner.url
```

html

```
{% for banner in banners %}
<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ banner.get_banner_url }}" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">{{banner.title}}</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

for be sure that your URL is coming try this(just for test):

```
 <div class="text">{{banner.get_banner_url }}</div>
```

if you can't see the URL that means it is about your media tags
settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [  
  #your paths  
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```